# bulk merging mpeg-4 audio files with video files

Tags: ffmpeg

I have tried downloading a large playlist from youtube but managed to make a mistake of just downloading the video for it. I then tried to get youtube-dl to try to use the already downloaded video to not waste time but filed to do that. In the end I managed to get a bunch of mp4 files and m4a files downloaded with each corresponding name of video matched with audio.
I tried

```
ffmpeg -i *.mp4 -i *.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy *-merged.mp4
```

but then I got

```
File '02 - Operational Procedures-yTOpBMNkOrA.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] N
```

I don't really know how to go forward with this. My goal is to merge all files with names maching each other into -merged.mp4.
For context I downlowedwd format 140 and format 134 a audio and video format respectively.

Comment: Answer depends on your OS.

Comment: Arch linux. Didn't know it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg` doesn't accept wildcards (aside from a few irrelevant exceptions such as the image demuxer).

Use a *for loop* instead. Bash example:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i "${f%.*}.m4a" -c copy "${f%.*}-merged.mp4"; done
```

Adapted from [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)